# Further question on Intel graphics driver

Tags: drivers

Ok, Josh answered almost immed.!  I need to know specifically, now that I am using Nvidia card effectively, do I need to allow update manager to update the intel gr. drivers?

I must add, I believe I know why Update Manager is telling me I need to update those Intel gr. drivers.  It probably happened because I tried to update my nvidia drivers and got a buggy install, which let to to a black screen.  I shut the system down manually after that and rebooted to a black screen and upon a further reboot I ascertained that I could still dual-boot(windows 7) into the other os.  Then I went through the restart process and at the grub2 menu chose other options and it was probably, at that time, that Linux was smart enough to know that nvidia drivers as installed weren't cutting it, and reverted to the onboard Intel graphics system...does that make sense?  Anyway, after successfully getting up and running, I reinstalled my old but successful nvidia drivers and all was well again, except now upon running Update Manager, I am offered the Intel graphics driver upgrade each time, which, up til now I have unchecked...my question is now more obvious.  Should I accept the Intel driver update and if I do, will it once again override my nvidia drivers?

Comment: It will keep bugging you if you don't. There should be no harm in keeping the Intel driver up-to-date, in case you need it again.

Answer (score 1):

You will not have to update the Intel Driver, unless you plan on using it again at some point... But the update manager may update it anyways.. if it does don't worry about it..

It shouldn't override your NVidia drivers...

You can blacklist the update though if you don't want to install it... Although I haven't done this in forever (hadn't needed to) but it might make for another good, but separate question...

Answer (score -1):

Look ubuntu support the intel graphics.
if you using Nvidia card so you have to update your Nvidia driver.
Look up your top panel one of applet is named additional driver.
In here you can update your Nvidia driver.
you also find t from system--Administration--additional driver.

Comment: I would like to think I have learned from reading the answers here, and I have.  But some of the things I have stated here about the Intel graphics drivers are just plain stupid, aren't they?  After all, the monitors(2) are both plugged into the Nvidia card, not the generic Intel graphics slots on the motherboard.  A huge big Trusty duh.  An ice-cream moment!  In my defense, no one suggested that what I thought was occurring could possible occur, either.  ps Trusty forever!